# How to cache a JavaScript file for 24 hours only?

Tags: javascript, caching, bookmarklet, cache-control

I'm working on a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) and would like to have it cached for 24 hours only, after that time it should be reloaded from the original source.
I thought about adding a date variable, e.g. `http://bookmarklet.example.com/js/bookmarklet.js?todaysDate` - would that work?

```
javascript:(function () {document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'http://bookmarklet.example.com/js/bookmarklet.js'}());
```

Comment: That should do the trick.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Do you see the problem? `javascript:(var currentTime = new Date() var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1 var day = currentTime.getDate() var year = currentTime.getFullYear() function () {document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'http://bookmarklet.example.com/js/bookmarklet.js?v=month+"-"+day+"-"+year'}());`